# How to delete local stored Chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome

I created a local webpage to generate and download 2000 images.
Chrome died during the process.

Now whenever I start Chrome it auto-close after 8 seconds.

I deleted Chrome data in the browser history and uninstalled/installed Chrome but nothing changes.

What I can see is that when I open Chrome something like 27 subprocess starts aswell (even tho I deleted all Chrome history so not a single tabs is openned): [image about the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zav8M.png)

I'm wondering what to do at that point ? Is it a folder on the computer that I can safely delete ?

Comment: Does it still happen if you open an incognito window?

Comment: It also creates like over 20 sub process but it doesn't seem to crash

Comment: That's pretty normal. With Chrome closed, you could try deleting the entire profile folder: `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ ` but you **will** lose anything not synced or backed up like passwords/bookmarks. If it still misbehaves, you can try deleting the parent User Data folder as well.

Comment: Your Chrome process is using 15GB of memory. Chrome is likely configured to automatically restore your session. Uninstalling Chrome does not delete your Chrome profile.

Comment: @Ramhound and how should I do that ?